# Positivity of solution for Fisher-Kolmogorov Equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

How can we prove that if $y=y(t,x)$ is the solution of the problem:

$$\begin{cases} \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}(t,x)-d\Delta y(t,x)=r(x)y(t,x)-\rho(x) y^2(t,x),\ (t,x)\in  (0,T)\times \Omega \\ \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\nu}(t,x)=0,\ (t,x)\in (0,T)\times\partial\Omega \\ y(0,x)=y_0(x)\geq 0,\ x\in \Omega\end{cases}$$

then $y(t,x)\geq 0$ on $(0,T)\times\Omega$?

I cannot apply the maximum principle for parabolic equation because of the logistic nonlinear term. All the derivatives are in the distributional sense and the solution $y$ is mild, i.e. $y\in C([0,T],L^2(\Omega))$.

We assume that $r,\rho\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ are positive. I read in some article that the maximum principle can be applied but I cannot see how...

I have the same question for a nonlocal logistic term of the form: $$y(t,x)\int_{\Omega} \varrho(x,x')y(t,x') dx'$$

where $\varrho\in L^{\infty}(\Omega\times\Omega)$. How can we prove that if the above problem (with this nonlocal logistic term ) has a solution, then it must be positive?

Comment: To apply the maximum principle, all you have to do is write the right hand side of your equation as $c(x,t)y$. The dependence of $c$ on the unknown function does not change anything.

Comment: But $c$ must have a superior bound on $(0,T)\times\Omega$. I cannot see how can we prove that having the quadratic term there. We have: $c(t,x)=r-\rho y$ which may be unbounded.

Comment: $y$ is bounded at least if the initial condition is. The rest should be doable by approximation.

Comment: I see, but that cannot be applied globally. It's like a loop here. I need this result to show that $y$ is bounded by a comparison principle. In the articles that I have read about the existence of a global solution to a reaction-diffusion system the authors proved that the problem has a bounded solution by using that the solution is positive (from maximum principle). My question is how can this principle be applied to such a common problem? Are there some weaker assumptions on $c(t,x)$?

Comment: It is bootstrap rather than loop. We may apply the maximum principle until $y$ is (lower) bounded thus getting that it is positive when is lower bounded. But then it is always positive (you reach a contradiction for $t>T$ close to $T$, the last point where $y(\cdot, \tau)$ is positive). However you need some regularity for applying the maximum principle to $y$.

Comment: Even if we have regularity, I don't see why we reach a contradiction...We can apply the maximum principle only on those intervals $[0,t]$ where we know that $y$ is bounded. From the maximum principle we do not get that $y\geq 0$ for in $[0,t+\varepsilon)$. And if $y(0,\cdot)$ is bounded it does not mean that $y(t,\cdot)$ is bounded even for small values of $t$. We can have $y=y_0(x)+tz(x)$ where $z\in L^2(\Omega)\setminus L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. It's still not clear for me how can we prove the positivity for this simple problem...

Comment: Are there other techniques to prove the positivity of $y$? I know about positive semigroups (Nagel 86) but I cannot see how can we apply this on our problem